# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name' Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

So I have a get function

```
class HorseEquipmentView(APIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'horse'

    def get (self, request, format = None):
        horse = 1     
        if horse != None:
            tab = []
            #queryset = HorseEquipment.objects.raw('SELECT H.horse_id, E.name FROM horse_equipment H JOIN equipment E ON H.equipment_id = E.id WHERE H.horse_id =' + str(horse))
            queryset = HorseEquipment.objects.filter(horse_id=horse).select_related("equipment")
            for i in queryset:
                i.equipment = Equipment.objects.filter(id = 1).name  
            #equipment = HorseEquipment.objects.filter(horse_id=horse).select_related('equipment')
            serializer = HorseEquipmentSerializer(queryset, many = True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my Equipment Model:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'equipment'
```

So it has id and name attributes but somehow it gives me error on my get function, precisely on my for loop where I refer to "name" attribute. Can you help me find out what's wrong?

Comment: You need to re-read the section about `objects.filter(...)` vs `objects.get(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `.filter()` which will return a `QuerySet` and not a instance of a model. You should use `.get()` for this scenario to access the `name` attribute.

Replace:

```py
Equipment.objects.filter(id=1).name
```

With

```py
Equipment.objects.get(id=1).name
```